# How to populate a table's foreign keys from other tables?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, mysql-workbench

I have a database with the following tables:

**Airport** ( iata **PK**, airport, city, state, country, lat, long)

**cancellation_cause** ( cod_cancellation **PK**, description)

**Manufaturer** (id_manufacturer **PK**, manufacturer_name)

**Model** (id_model **PK**, model_name, id_manufacturer **FK**)

**Airline**( airline_code **PK**, description)

**airplane_type** (id_AirplaneType **PK**, airplane_type)

**engine_type** (id_engine **PK**, engine_tyoe)

**Aircraft_type** (id_aircraft **PK**, aircraft_type)

**Airplane** (TailNumber **PK,** id_model **FK**, id_aircraft **FK**, airline_code **FK**, id_AirplaneType **FK**, id_engine **FK**, Issue_date, status, year)

**Flight** (id_flight **PK**, cod_cancellation **FK**, TailNumber **FK**, iata_origin **FK**, iata_destin **FK**, Year, Month, DayofMonth, DayofWeek, DepTime, CRSTime, ArrTime, CRSArrTime, FlightNum, AtualElapsedTime, CRSElapsedTime, AirTime, ArrDelay, DepDelay, distane, TaxiIn, TaiOut, Cancelled, Diverted, CarrierDelay, WeatherDelay, NASDelay, SecurityDelay, LateAircraftDelay)

*Note: PK - Primary Key;  FK - Foreign Key*

I have a csv file "flights" with millions of records containing information such as "TailNumber, AirlineCode, etc." for each of the flights.

Also have a supplementary csv "Airplane" with information about the plane (TailNumber, engine type, year, etc.)

In tables Flight, Airplane and Model some fields can be copied directly but I don't know how to load data from foreign keys correctly.

Someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you already have *all* the Airports?  Some of them?  None of them?  The details depend on which case you are doing.

Two steps (per normalization table):  `INSERT...SELECT DISTINCT ... LEFT JOIN .. WHERE .. IS NULL` to add to normalization table.  Then `UPDATE ... SELECT ... JOIN...` to get the ids back.

The [code here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization) is aimed at the "some of them" case, bu probably works for all 3 cases.

If you actually have `FOREIGN KEY` constraints enabled, be careful of the order of performing operations -- else you could get errors.

Comment: I have many airports, not all. This code gave me idea how populate the tables using INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN. Thanks